# pass a string to an R function argument but later use as another function's argument name

Tags: r, dplyr

In my data analyses, there are many variables that I would like end-users to specify as a argument value in an R function:

```
myFun = function(var.name = "age") { ... }
```

Inside this `myFun` function, I also want to use `var.name` as a subsetting argument in `dplyr` to the data frame `dat1`:

```
dat1.level1 = filter(dat1, var.name == ">18")
dat1.level2 = filter(dat1, var.name == "<=18")
```

I don't know when users pass a string to `var.name` such as "age" which is also the column name of the data frame, how can I later use this `var.name` for future subsetting (as described above)? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use an alternative to the non-standard evaluation calls. Here's how you might do it

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

myFun <- function(var.name = "cyl") {
    print(var.name)
    mtcars %>% filter_(.dots=interp(~x==4, x=as.name(var.name)))
}
myFun()
myFun("carb")
```

For more information, see the vignette included with dplyr on this topic: `vignette("nse")`